# How to revert a frame to inherited when it contains a control aligned to client?

Tags: delphi, dfm

I sometimes design a frame where there are controls all over the place. It could be a grid with align=alClient, or maybe some panels and splitters. Or it could be something else entirely. Anyway, when I want to "revert to inherited" I have to make space for right-clicking by setting align=alNone and move a control, or edit the DFM directly. This is somewhat cumbersome. Granted, this happens rarely enough not to be a big deal, but still, it bugs me. It would help if I could right-click in the structure view, but alas, this doesn't work.

Has anyone else noticed this, and if so; How do you deal with it? Like me, with silent (well, so far at least) annoyance, or have you found a brilliant solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select the control in the Form Designer. If the control is obscured by a child control, then select the child control, and then press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to select the parent. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to activate the context menu.

Comment: Or the 'menu' key that every modern Windows keyboard has (though I also use Shift+F10)